# multiple condition in where statement

Tags: sql

| name | brand_name | item_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| HP laptop | HP | 500 |
| :sony camera |  | 1000 |
| laptop | Toshiba | 200 |
| iPhone |  | 0 |
| canon camera | canon | 300 |
| canon camera |  | 200 |

this is a table I have I want to return only the products with empty brand_name column but the name column starts with this list of brand "HP,sony, canon , Chanel "
how to do that so I can only get this values

| name | brand_name | item_sold |
| --- | --- | --- |
| :sony camera |  | 1000 |
| canon camera |  | 200 |

I have 2 queries but I want to combine them into one.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, your query pretty much has nothing to do with the question above it.  Perhaps your question needs more explanation.

Comment: @GordonLinoff it does but I want to include the second query to the first one so I can get an output similar to the above one

Comment: It's not clear what issue you're having - per your description you want `SELECT ... WHERE b.brand_name = '' AND name IN (':sony camera', 'canon camera');`. Is there a reason this query doesn't return the results you listed?

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones when I do that it won't give the field brand_name empty

Comment: @WOUNDEDStevenJones plus my table contains hundreds of rows so I don't know the exact name for each so I can't use WHERE b.brand_name = '' AND name IN (':sony camera', 'canon camera');

Comment: @Nikki9696 this join for other purpose it gives me a column from another table in other database

Comment: @Nikki9696 the query works but I want to add a condition

Comment: sorry, I deleted my comment. I noticed the "limit 10" - please tag your dbms, that's not sql server, which is my usual realm

Comment: try rlike, if that's available in your db.  You'll need a regular expression, maybe `brand rlike '^(hp|sony|canon|chanel)"`.  The ^ matches the beginning of the line and the rest is a list of line beginnings to match.

Comment: (**Note**: You need to get moderator intervention to get information from posts removed for good while keeping the post.)

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to do this

```
WITH (
  VALUES ('HP'),
         ('Acer'),
         ('VAKIND'),
         ('Casio'),
         ('Lenovo'),
         ('BF1 Soul'), 
         ('Sony')
 ) as lookup(val)
 SELECT 
    -- some sql statement
 FROM some_table
 LEFT JOIN lookup on some_table.brand_name = lookup.val
 WHERE lookup.val is null
```

Note -- lookup table can be a dynamically created table like I do here or you can make the table an actual table and control the functionality of the query by changing the table.

Answer (score 0):

Your question seems a bit contradictory or I got it wrong. Your input is incomplete. You did not specify your tables. I have listed the combination of your two queries below. I do not know if it will help you or not.

```
SELECT name
 ,item_sold_30d
 ,brand_name
 ,category_name
,product_url
 FROM (
 SELECT DISTINCT b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name, a.product_url,                 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.name,b.item_sold_30d , b.brand_name ,b.category_name ORDER BY  a.product_url) as rowId
  FROM "dasync"."outputs_lazada_my" a
  INNER JOIN 
  (select brand_name,name,item_sold_30d,b.category_name
from "catalog-my"."catalog_my_20210425" 
 where store_merchant_id like '%lazada%' and name in ('HP','Acer','VAKIND','Casio','Lenovo','BF1 Soul','Sony','Lenovo','Samsung','Bosch','Xiaomi',
'Panasonic','Dell','Rondaful','Toshiba','UCUC',
'zanzea','CAMERON SINO','ZZOOI','Canon','Philips','LEGO','Glamorousky','ZeroQiQi','Baosity','Huawei'
,'Alloet','Hontinga','OME','Jotun','Yamaha')
 group by brand_name,name,item_sold_30d,b.category_name) b on b.name = a.name
 where b.brand_name = ''
  ORDER BY b.item_sold_30d DESC
   ) dt
  WHERE dt.rowId = 1
  limit 10;
```